# What will happen when a class are full of static member function and variable in Java?

Tags: java

If I define a class which is full of static member function and variable(java), then something interesting may happen.

Can I use the class as a single instance of the class and have no need worrying about conveying the instance variable?

How will the construction function take effect if I don't instantiate an object? So I can't initialize the static member variable in construction function, right?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself and come back with your **interesting** results?

Comment: You may want to look into the "Singleton" design pattern.
Initializing static variables can otherwise be done when you declare them, or in a "static block" - another thing to possibly Google.

Comment: Why don't you write some code and see if it does what you expect? If it doesn't, come back with a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1):

**If I define a class which are full of static member function and variable(java), then something interesting may happen.**

Not really, usually helper / utility classes don't have instance level fields.They only have static methods and static fields.

**Can I use the class as a single instance of the class and have no need worrying about conveying the instance variable**

No, marking all methods and fields as `static` won't make this a *Singleton* class.

**How will the construction function take effect if I don't instantiate an object**

The default constructor will be called when you do `new MyClass()`.

**So I can't initialize the static member variable in construction function, right?**

You can. Unless it is marked as `final`. You might run into trouble if you have static blocks

Answer (score 0):

It is working same as any other class with static members, no matter if all of them are static or only part of them. They are used as expected - bound to class, not to instance.

Also you can actually have "static class" with constructor, look for Singleton pattern (however be aware, that pattern can be misused very easily).